# Loquacious Nhibernate not able to access non-public properties for mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm converting from fluent to loquacious, and I've run in to an issue with a non-public property. When I try to map it, nhibernate throws an exception that null value for the memberInfo. I got the latest source code and stepped through to see what was happening, and it looks like this call:

```
memberOfReflectType = typeof (TEntity).GetProperty(memberOfDeclaringType.Name, memberOfDeclaringType.GetPropertyOrFieldType());
```

Is the one that is causing the issue. memberOfReflectType gets set to null and then in the PropertyPath Constructor it breaks when it tries to access it.

My mapping looks like this:

```
public class Foo
{
  public virtual int SomePublicInt {get; set;}
  protected internal virtual int _someProtectedInt {get; set;}
}

public class FooMap : ClassMapping<Foo>
{
  public FooMap ()
  {
    Table("Foo");
    ComposedId(compIDMapper =>
    {
      compIDMapper.Property(x => x.SomePublicInt, m => m.Column("SomePublicInt"));
      compIDMapper.Property(x => _someProtectedInt, m => m.Column("SomeProtectedInt"));
    });
  }
}
```

If I change the Protected Internal int to a public one, it works fine, but it seems like you should be able to map protected internal. We could do this with nhibernate without any issues.

Is there some additional mapping command I have to put in to fix this? I googled around for awhile, but didn't come up with anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For non-public fields, try the overload with string instead of lambda expression:

```
compIDMapper.Property("_someProtectedInt", m => m.Column("SomeProtectedInt"));
```

Comment: this fixes it, but do you know why it is needed?

Comment: Not really sure, probably connected with NHibernate's proxying abilities. Lambda-typed overloads are for public members only.